# Non-Commutative Analogue of Integration

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, definite-integrals, noncommutative-algebra

I am working on an idea involving taking the partial sum of a sequence of elements from a monoid to see if that sequence possesses certain properties.  But the "+" operation in my partial sum need not be commutative since I am working with a monoid.  I can certainly generalize this partial sum idea when dealing with the standard commutative integration, but was wondering if there exists generalizations of integration where the "+" operation in the definition of the definite integral is not necessarily commutative.  One possible property of such a hypothetical integral is that $\int^a_{-a}f(x)dx \neq \int^a_{-a}f(-x)dx$.

Let me know if I need to provide more information for a better response.